# Change CSS using JQuery (Animation)

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate

Im trying to stop or remove the animation on CSS using jquery but it wont work.I'm making a skeleton loading and trying to stop the CSS animation when the page load.

CSS

```css
[data-placeholder]::after {
   content: " ";
   box-shadow: 0 0 50px 9px rgba(254,254,254);
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: -100%;
   height: 100%; 
   animation: load 1s infinite;
}
@keyframes load {
   0%{ left: -100%}
   100%{ left: 150%}
}
```

Here on jquery

```js
$(window).on("load", function() {
  $("#press").fadeOut("slow");
  $("[data-placeholder]").css("animation", "");
});
```

HTML

`<button id="'.$UID2.'" onclick="openow(this)" data-placeholder class="relative flex justify-between bg-gray-50 rounded-3xl bg-cover text-gray-800 overflow-hidden cursor-pointer w-44> Click Me</button>`

Comment: You can add a class to this `[data-placeholder]` and override the animation using that class.

Comment: Correct me if im wrong, its like i will create a separate class with .data placeholder to overwrite the animation if used?

Comment: Yes, exactly, I have explained it in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pseudo-elements are part of the Shadow DOM, so they can't be directly modified. However, you can use classes to to modify them, here's a work around.

**jQuery**

```
$(function () { // document ready state
    $("[data-placeholder]").addClass('stop-animation');
});
```

**CSS**

```
.stop-animation:after {
    animation: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe can try this solution:

css:

```
.noAnimation {
    animation: none;
// or
    animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

js:

```
$("#press").fadeOut("slow", function() {
    $("[data-placeholder]").addClass('noAnimation');
});
```

the other solution:

js:

```
$("#press").fadeOut("slow", function() {
    $("[data-placeholder]").remove();
});
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you for attention. I add HTML on the post so you can see where im implementing the class. I'll try this

Comment: you should add the noAnimation class to [data-placeholder] or the element you want to stop its animation, take care that you should do it when the animation has finished. other solution is mentioned too...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to target the `::after` pseudo element using javascript directly,since it is part of the DOM.
One solution you can try is appending a style tag containing the exact css, to the `head` or `body` of html.
Something like this:

```
$("body").append('<style>[data-placeholder]:after{animation:none}</style>');
```

in above solution, the selector is directly targeted with the css required.

So, the final javascript will look like this:

```
$(window).on("load", function() {
  $("#press").fadeOut("slow");
  $("body").append('<style>[data-placeholder]:after{animation:none}</style>');
});
```

Comment: Pseudo-elements are **not** part of DOM, they are part of Shadow DOM, and you should be using `head` instead of the `body` since it is good approach to use `style` in `head`.